# Update Billing Email Addresses in Sage MAS90

Tags: sql-server-2005, microsoft-access-2007, odbc, sage

I have been tasked with trying to find a method of updating about 500 customer email addresses in MAS90. I recently discovered that they had the ability to email invoices to their customers and because I opened my big mouth, they now want me to find a way to add about 500 emails into the system so they do not have to perform the task manually.

The office does have an SQL server which supports ASP sites which contains a list of all of the current email addresses. My plan was to use Microsoft Access 2007 with the MAS90 ODBC connector to attempt this update.

My questions are:
Is this the right way to go or is there a better method of obtaining these results?
Does anyone happen to know which tables I should be looking at?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Super User is more geared for end-user type questions.  offhand i think this is more of a Server Fault question.  please don't crosspost; this question will be migrated if necessary.  (flag for moderator attention if you'd like it migrated sooner.)  (if other close-voting members of the community have opinions as to where this should be migrated, if anywhere, please vote to migrate as appropriate, or leave comments as to why it should stay here.)

Comment: I posted it here because someone had posted a mas90 question on serverfault and it had been migrated here. I do agree though, this sounds more like a server fault question.

article: http://serverfault.com/questions/49642/sage-change-company-address-closed